# Determining whether a MySQL column is ever used

Tags: mysql, access-control

How can I determine whether a particular column in a MySQL table is ever SELECTed or explicitly UPDATEd or INSERTed or referenced in a WHERE clause?  It'd be nice if I could determine the db user who is using the column, too.

This is on MySQL 5.0, but I could move that to 5.6 or 5.7.

*Background:*  I'm maintaining a legacy app with an AUTOINCREMENT field (`"id"`) that will foreseeably reach its maximum INT value before the app is retired.

I suspect, but do not know, that no one actually references this field in SQL at all.  Ideally I'd "monitor" the column for a week or two and, if it appeared in no queries, I'd turn it into a BIGINT or drop it in favor of a natural key.  If the column does appear in someones' queries, I'll need to track that person down and coordinate the change.

Comment: All you need to worry about for auto_incrementing are `INSERT`s. YOu can put in a `TRIGGER` to log this. Why would detecting `SELECT`s affect anything?

Comment: @Vérace, is my edit clearer?  I want to get rid of this column but only if I'm sure it won't break any actual use.

Comment: Still don't see what the problem is. Nobody's `UPDATE`ing this column, so the auto_increment won't be affected. No need to change it to BIGINT - seems like you're looking for work which isn't there.

Comment: @Vérace, people still INSERT into this table, and `id` is populated implicitly.  Hence the possibility that the `id` field will hit its maximum unless I do something.  Anything I do in DML to that column risks confounding a client that assumes that the `id` field exists and is an INT.

Comment: OK, why not just modify your column to a [BIGINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)?

Comment: @Vérace because a client naively written in C (for example) that assumes that `id` is a signed INT might misbehave when the value exceeds its implicit expectation.

Comment: Do you have the source code for this client?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41928/discussion-between-pilcrow-and-verace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mind the Gap**

Let me give you a third option if the ids have a lot of gaps...

One significant cause of "running out of id values" is queries that leave gaps in `AUTO_INCREMENT` values.  An `INSERT` statements where row is not inserted first allocates an auto-inc value, then fails to use it.  `INSERT IGNORE` will do this silently.

Sometimes a useful workaround is to change the code such that it does not do the `INSERT` if it is not going to succeed.  Normalization is perhaps a normal case for this.  [Here is a technique for batch normalization that avoids the problem](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization).

(OK, this suggestion is not useful if you can't get to the source code.  But it could be useful to other readers; it has saved me a few times.)

**General log**

By turning on the "general log" for a period of time, you can collect all queries.  Then you can search for the table or "id", etc.  It will be tedious.  It will not be 100% safe, since some queries may not have been executed during that time.

**innodb_autoinc_lock_mode**

`innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` did not exist until 5.5, so that is not an option.

(Again, I mention this for other readers.)